# Drawing .png image like a path

Tags: android, graphics, draw, paint, imagebrush

So I have a PNG file which I am using as a custom brush in my app. As a motion event takes place, I keep redrawing it to give a brush effect. But if I drag too fast I miss pixels and some brushes look really bad - like the images are just drawn over each other.

Is there any way I can draw it in a `drawpath` mode instead?

The code below is my `onDraw` method.  The `mbitmapBrush` variable has the PNG image file, and `pos.a` and `pos.b` are the current motion event 'x' and 'y' coordinates.

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint=mPaint;
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
mCM.set(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, 0f, 1f,
    0f, 1f, 3f, 0f, 4f,
    1f, 4f, 1f, 1f, 0f,
    1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f });
ColorMatrixColorFilter cm3=new ColorMatrixColorFilter(mCM);

paint.setColorFilter(cm3);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        for (Vector2 pos : mPositions) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapBrush, pos.a, pos.b, paint);
            //canvas.drawCircle(pos.a, pos.b, 7, mPaint);
        }

        //canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapBrush, clickX, clickY, null);
        //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a custom `SurfaceView` and calling the `draw()` method manually from a loop? That way you have more control over the rate at which it draws.

Comment: Yup trying that, also will using `getHistoricalX` and `getHistoricalY` help in making more drawing points. Under what condition can i run the loop to make it draw more points?

Comment: If you are updating the position every time `onTouch()` is called then you are already getting the best temporal resolution possible. I would create a thread and have a while loop that calls `mySurface.draw()` and then sleeps for say 20 milliseconds each time it loops. Alternatively you could just call `draw()` every time `onTouch()` is called.

Comment: Hey, im new to the Graphics API, i Got the manual calling of the method, working alot smoother but not in the surface view. could you please give me a small snippet of code, just something to show the working of surfaceview. Thanks

Comment: This should help you get to grips with extending `SurfaceView`: http://www.gamingfordroids.com/2011/09/drawing-with-surfaceview.html